# How to convert fmri brain volumes to brain graph

Tags: neuroimaging, fmri, alzheimer

I am working with fMRI data of Alzheimer's Disease (AD) patients. I want to convert brain volumes to brain graph and then using different graph metrics, I want to classify the brain volumes in AD and non-AD class.
The paper I want to implement is "[Automatic classification of Alzheimer's disease with resting-state fMRI and graph theory](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25907414)".

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to implement this algorithm? How to acquire this fMRI data?

Comment: I acquired dataset from ADNI. Now I have to classify this into AD/nonAD class. Can you tell me how to preprocess the data and how to extract features from data. The paper says that fmri images are converted into a graph and then graph features are extracted from it. How can this be done

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you unclear of how the algorithm works? Have you tried to implement this algorithm in software and are having difficulty with it?

Comment: I have no prior experience in neuroimaging and I want to start with this paper. I don't have any idea about how to start implementing this. I want a step by step procedure to implement this paper.

Comment: This really isn't the site to give you a step-by-step procedure. We'll be happy to help you once you've chosen a software package, started analysis and then have questions!